# How can I preserve whitespaces at line endings in listings?

Tags: listings, white-space

I want to display a Whitespace program (an esoteric programming language) in a listing. Even with `keepspaces=true`, spaces at line endings are discarded (and lines only consisting of whitespaces at the end of the program are discarded, too).

I found a workaround: add some special character at each line ending and make this character invisible via literate setting (see below).

However, I do not like this solution since it requires the modification of the program's source code.
Is there a way to preserve all whitespace characters at line ending?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{Whitespace}{
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=true,
    showtabs=true,
    tab=\rightarrowfill,
    tabsize=4,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    literate={€}{{}}1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Whitespace,frame=single]
     €
    €
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The result is as intended. However, I want to get it work with the following code (note that unfortunately stackexchange removes the whitespaces in the code, too):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Whitespace,frame=single]


\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As part of TeX's efforts to be portable across different architectures, including operating systems that use fixed length records not just operating systems that use an end-of-line marker. Spaces are unconditionally removed from ends of lines and any operating system end of line markers are removed. This happens unconditionally, the only thing you can control is whether any character token is inserted to mark the end of line, and if so, which that is (normally it is `^^M`)

With luatex I think you can grab the file earlier, but in classic tex or xetex then you would have to change the program itself.

Comment: Okay, seems that I have to stay with my solution whenever I include the source code into the tex file directly.
What about \lstinputlisting? Could an external file be handled differently by TeX? (I mean, binary files such as images can be processed by TeX.)

Comment: @Matthias not really, images are not handled by classic tex (`\includegraphics` just puts the name of the file in the dvi file, not the file itself) even pdftex which acts as its own driver and does include the image uses a completely separate code path related to the pdf writing, the image data isn't available to tex macros in any useful way.

Comment: It may be possible by changing the `\catcode` of 9, 10, 13 and 32, but this may cause troubles with detecting the `\end{lstlisting}`.

Comment: @pts no: catcodes have no effect here